# RODBC vs ODBC: RODBC is giving wrong result with while loop of SQL server

Tags: r, sql-server, loops, odbc, rodbc

I am trying to run an sql query which needs to run in a loop. I tried running the query using both RODBC and ODBC. I find that query runs fine if I use ODBC package but not if I use RODBC package. I find that it can return results for only one loop: Please see MWE below:

```
install.packages('odbc')
install.packages('RODBC')

library(RODBC)
library(odbc) 
library(DBI)

## No loop Code
res = RODBC::sqlQuery(Rcon, query = "SELECT 1 as A", as.is=TRUE)
res
#  A
#1 1

df <- dbGetQuery(Ocon, statement ="SELECT 1 as A")
df
#  A
#1 1

## Loop Code
q1 = paste("         
            DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2022-07-28';
            DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2022-07-29';
            
            WHILE (@StartDate <= @EndDate)
            BEGIN
            Select  1 AS A
            set @StartDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @StartDate);
            END;
            "
           , collapse = "")
res = RODBC::sqlQuery(dbsqlcn, query = q1, as.is=TRUE)
res
#  A
#1 1

df <- dbGetQuery(con, statement = q1)
df
#  A
#1 1
#2 1
```

How to make RODBC package display all the results?

Comment: Call a procedure?

Comment: There is no such thing as SQL Server 18; the latest version of SQL Server is version 16 (SQL Server 2022) which is currently in preview. The latest released version is version 15 (2019), and prior to that was version 14 (2017).

Comment: And I see no loop...

Comment: @Limey there is a while loop in the sql.

Comment: Why do you think your query needs to be in a loop? Almost certainly it doesn't. Loops are horrible for performance.

Comment: *How to resolve the issue with RODBC package?* ... what is the issue? Error? Undesired result? *not working..* is not a good descriptor for us. Also, please post the working `odbc` package version.

Comment: @SeanLange so there is.  I retract.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you pointing it out. I have made changes to my title.

Comment: @Sean Lange I want to use loop due to memory issues in my system. I want to return results in small chunks.

Comment: Even several thousand rows would be small in size, @Rahi . The contents of this webpage alone, including CSS files, images, etc, is probably larger in size that a dataset containing a many thousands of rows. SQL Server is *very* good at handling 100,000's of rows at a time, even millions and more, efficiently with a well written *set based* statement.

Comment: @Parfait I have edited the question. I want to know how to make RODBC package display correct results.  I am not sure, if I got it right. The odbc version as given in system is SQL Server Native Client 11.0

Comment: @Larnu ok. I will keep that in mind. Thanks.